# How to convert YYYY-MM to YYYYMM?

Tags: r, sorting, statistics, analytics, data-cleaning

I have a dates column which is `YYYY-MM` and in another file it is `YYYY-month` in alphabets, I want to convert them in `YYYYMM`. 
Date in one file :

```
2016-04 want > 201604
```

Date in another file :

```
2011-AUG want > 201108
```

The date column is "character"

Also the date column has over 100k observations with each date being different in rows. Need a code which runs across the whole column. Thank you!

Comment: These are not bona fide date values, because there is no day component.  What is your intention for using this data?

Comment: `format(as.Date(paste0("2016-04", "-01"), "%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y%m")`  and
`format(as.Date(paste0("2016-AUG", "-01"), "%Y-%B-%d"), "%Y%m")`

Comment: This is like a data provided by some company and I need to have this in YYYYMM format to see which observation came first. The date column in a "character"

Comment: Thanks for the help here but I need to run this all across the date column, how do you think this is gonna across the column with different inputs in every row?

Comment: Instead of hardcoded date just replace it with the column. It should work as far as every value in the column has the same date format. For example - `format(as.Date(paste0(df$Datecolumn, "-01"), "%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y%m")`

Comment: Yep it works, thanks a ton!

Comment: ronak, instead of comment can you post the answer, others may benefit

Comment: Much apologies @akrun, my question had a lot of errors and it was for excel and not R(messed up due to work pressure
)